# Как перенести максимальное число на первое место?

Tags: python

Напишите программу queue.py, которая принимает первым аргументом командной строки последовательность чисел разделенных пробелами, а после ставит самое большое число на первое место и выводит новую очередь на экран. Попробовал вот так:

```
f = [12, 56, 17, 34, 12, 45, 89, 22, 101, 52]
f.sort(reverse=True)
print(f)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добиться правильного ответа?

Comment: Что делает sort()? А что нужно сделать на самом деле?

Comment: А почему так не работает? У меня всё нормально

Comment: а где реализация самой очереди то? смотрю ответы, но никто не задал автору вопроса, почему речь об очередях в вопросе.

Answer (score 5):

Делайте по шагам:

- Находите максимальное значение в списке
- Определяете индекс максимального значения
- Удаляете значение из списка
- Добавляете его в начало списка

Пример:

```
f = [12, 56, 17, 34, 12, 45, 89, 22, 101, 52]
max_num = max(f)
idx_max_num = f.index(max_num)
f.pop(idx_max_num)
f.insert(0, max_num)
print(f)
# [101, 12, 56, 17, 34, 12, 45, 89, 22, 52]
```

---

**UPD.**

Если индексов несколько, то можно собрать их индексы, удалить их (в обратном порядке, это важно!) и добавить в начало элементы в количестве индексов

*Алгоритм сборки индексов можно оптимизировать, если использовать `index`, счетчик чисел и сразу же удалять максимальное число*

Пример:

```
f = [12, 56, 17, 101, 34, 12, 45, 101, 89, 22, 101, 52]
max_num = max(f)
idxs_max_num = [i for i, x in enumerate(f) if x == max_num]
for i in idxs_max_num[::-1]:
    f.pop(i)
    
for _ in idxs_max_num:
    f.insert(0, max_num)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @user470505, пожалуйста :)

Comment: А если их несколько?)

Comment: @Qwertiy, добавил в UPD :)

Comment: Асимптотика квадратичная вместо линейной.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я честно написал, что алгоритм неэффективный :) Накидал такое https://pastebin.com/5wRCLPGC, нахождение максимальное числа и индексов в один заход и совместил добавление в начало списка с удаление из него, работает, но осталось чувство, что в этом "монстре" могла легко закрасться ошибка :)

Comment: Ну вообще, тут жирный вопрос, действительно ли надо изменять существующий список, или можно создать новый. Второй вариант проще. А у тебя снова квадратичный алгоритм потому что insert в 0 в цикле.

Comment: Я сделал свой вариант с изменением того же списка.

Answer (score 3):

Найдите максимум, удалите его, потом вставьте в начало

Answer (score 3):

Ещё вариант через списковое включение, нормально работающий если несколько раз максимум встречается:

```
f = [12, 56, 17, 34, 12, 45, 89, 22, 101, 52]
fmax = max(f)
fnew = [x for x in f if x == fmax] + [x for x in f if x != fmax]
print(fnew)
```

Вывод:

```
[101, 12, 56, 17, 34, 12, 45, 89, 22, 52]
```

- находим максимум
- создаём список где только максимум(ы)
- добавляем к нему список без максимума(мов)

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/kFAfY5

```
a = [12, 56, 17, 34, 101, 45, 89, 22, 101, 52]
 
x = max(a)
r = len(a) - 1
 
for l in range(r, -1, -1):
  if a[l] != x:
    a[r] = a[l]
    r -= 1
 
for i in range(r, -1, -1):
  a[i] = x
 
print(a)
```

Comment: Интересно и непонятно, по крайней мере, сходу не смог понять что происходит :)

Comment: @gil9red, сначала находим максимум, потом справа налево сдвигаем хвост пропуская максимальные элементы. А потом дописываем максимумы в начало. Что-то типа `[x for y in a if y == x] + [y for y in a if y != x]`, но на месте.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за пояснение :)

Answer (score 2):

первая мысль была правильная - надо использовать сортировку, просто еще надо добавить ключ:

```
f = [12, 56, 101, 17, 34, 12, 45, 89, 22, 101, 52]

f = sorted(f, key=lambda x: x!=max(f))
```

результат:

```
[101, 101, 12, 56, 17, 34, 12, 45, 89, 22, 52]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ очень прост:

```
f = [12, 56, 17, 34, 12, 45, 89, 22, 101, 52]
num = max(f)
f.remove(num)
f.insert(0,num)
print(f)
```

Comment: Собственно, MBo дал именно такой ответ, только без кода )  А потом пошли варианты - а что, если максимум несколько раз встречается...